# A Circular-Polarization Reconfigurable Meng-Shaped Patch Antenna

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism, pcb-antenna

How are the pin diodes in this [antenna with chinese character](https://sci-hub.tw/https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8458114) actually related to circular polarization ?
What are dimensions D and Fv in the paper?

[image: antenna dimension]

[image: pin diodes]

[image: circular polarization]

Comment: Who or what says that they are?

Comment: @Andyaka I suppose those pin diodes act as RF switches between circuitry for either LH or RH polarization ??  However, why does the author requires RF switches between these two ? 
And what do _D_ and _Fv_ mean in Figure 1(b) ?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the paper quality and concept itself...

Answering your question in the comment:

D in that figure is the diameter of the probe feed, I think. If you look at the bottom part of figure 1, you see that the antenna is made by using two separate PCBs that are spaced a significant distance apart. Fv is the height of these feeding probes.

Skimming over the paper, the 'antenna' they present can do both LH and RH polarization. This is probably because it two modes where it resonates, and by changing where/how you feed the antenna, you can change which mode you excite, and thus which polarization is radiated. This is what the diode switches are for. By turning one of the sets on, they can control which feed is connected to the input.

Comment: "Fv is the height of these feeding probes" <-- why would the probes be placed at a distance from the antenna ?

Comment: because this is a way to couple the signal in. It introduces some capacitance through which you feed the signal. This way you can tune the match of your feed. It has the added benefit of not having any connection at DC, which can be interesting in some situations.

Comment: **1.** What is Fh cos(α) for ?

   **2.** What are the purposes of angles α and β ?

   **3.** How do we simulate the distance H between two dielectric layers in HFSS ?